# How to include a custom class in a Symfony Bundle?

Tags: php, class, symfony

I have a Symfony bundle where I will have to use a custom class. This class does not have to be accessible from all the website, but just in a controller of this bundle.
I have seen a few solutions relative to the vendors, but this is quite heavy and not necessary in my case.
Does someone have a simpler solution?

Comment: `namespace Acme\MyBundle\Class`.. to use: `use Acme\MyBundle\Class\MyClass.php`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class must be created in `Acme\Bundle\Model` namespace and folder, **not** `\Class`! Who says this?!

```
// ../src/Acme/Bundle/Model/Utility.php
<?php namespace Acme\Bundle\Model;
class Utility:
..
```

Using in controllers:

```
<?php ..
use Acme\Bundle\Model\Utility;

$x = new Utility(); // FINE!:)
```

Name of file (`Utility.php`) must be equal to the class name.

Comment: Obviously, I said it, as I used the word `Class` as an example. Sorry you got hung up on the word and missed the sample :) The actual location of the class has really nothing to do with OP's problem.

Comment: Yeah i get you. Damn :)

Answer (score 20):

This is what [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) are for.

From [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php):

> What are namespaces? In the broadest definition namespaces are a way of encapsulating items.

Simply put, include your namespace at the top of your *custom* class.

**src/Acme/DemoBundle/Model/MyClass.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Model;

class MyClass { // ...
```

and use it in your Controller:

**src/Acme/SomeOtherBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\SomeOtherBundle\Controller;

// ...
use Acme\DemoBundle\Model\MyClass; # can be used in any class in any bundle
// ...

class DefaultController extends Controller { // ...
```

Comment: the `.php` at the end is not necessary, as every file under `src/` gets autoloaded.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did it, but in fact, I have no idea where the php file of the class must be located, and I don't know how to include it... (autoloads ?)

Comment: put it where it best belongs. I used the folder "_Class_" as an example. What is the custom class's  responsibility and what bundle does it relate to? For example, if it was an Entity you would put it in the an `Entity` folder within the Bundle that is related to. This is your decision.

Comment: It's a weather api class, and it belongs to the "DLS\EphemerideBundle"

Comment: Okay, so why not place it in a folder named `API` and if you're planning on having multiple "categories" of API you could do `API/Weather`.. The actual location would be something like `src/DLS/EphemerideBundle/API/Weather.php`

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it ! But how do I include the Weather.php file to make it accessible from my controller ? PHP is telling me my class doesn't exists :/

Comment: Please read the links in my answer. Properly using namespaces like in my examples will fix this. Also if you use the `generate:bundle` console command you can view a generated example of proper namespaces. You can also look in your vendor files if you need extra examples on how to use them.

Comment: I don't know how it works, but it works ! Thanks a lot and sorry for my ignoring...

Comment: DO AVOID using "Class" for directory name it is special and reserved key word in some cases, use instead "MyClass" or your choice.